# Howto configure tomcat logging in IDE in a short style

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging, intellij-idea

When tomcat is run from an IDE, it is usually not started using the startup script.
So logging configuration is not picked up.
Where do I need to put my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat initially uses java.util.logging to log. The format for that is not very easy to read.
To use a shorter logging output you must configure logging in a file. This file can either be the standard location defined by the startup script (%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties).
If tomcat is started from the IDE then the file name must be defined on the command line via:
"-Djava.util.logging.config.file=...your-tomcat-installation\conf\logging.properties"

Sample:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler  
.level= INFO  
#SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST, ALL  
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter  
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format= %1$TH:%1$TM:%1$TS %4$-5s %2$s: %5$s%n  
#results in:  
#16:26:26 INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load: Initialization processed in 201 ms  
#for the format see the javadoc of java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```